# Нужен совет какой подход использовать ML (NLP)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, nlp, sklearn, классификация

Имеется датасет на 1500 записей, 40 классов, не очень то уж и сбалансированный. [image: img]

для обучения использовал sklearn модели, и они давали результат +- 0.85acc.  текс разбивал на токены, убирал стоп слова и всякие знаки пунктуации.
Хочу как-то улучшить качество классификации до 0.9 , но не знаю каким бы образом это сделать и реально ли такое при таком маленьком датасете.

Comment: Вопрос не только в общем количестве записей, а ещё в том, сколько записей есть на каждый класс. И хорошо ли они у вас разделимы, эти классы. Вообще что в итоге то использовали - мешок слов `CountVectorizer`? И какую модель? На текстах обычно хорошо работают деревья, например `RandomForest`, и, как ни странно, `NaiveBayes`, остальное на текстах может плоховато работать из `sklearn` по моему опыту.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну CountVectorizer да.  Ну распределение записей по классом на картинке в вопрсе есть.  РадомФорест не пробовал, надо затестить. Я просто еще натыкалс на статьи про w2v pretrained true модели, которые можно дообучить на своём наборе данных. Не знаю вот какой способ лучше будет, а чтобы пробовать все возможные  - нет времени

Comment: А, да, распределение есть, туплю. Вопрос тогда в том, насколько отличаются наборы слов в этих классах. А так то это не такая страшная несбалансированность, бывает сильно хуже, типа бинарной классификации 1 к 100. С дообучением погодите пока, сначала с простыми вещами разберитесь. Попробуйте таки RF, может взлетит. Только кросс-валидацию не забудьте сделать, а то он легко переобучается, скор может быть хорошим, но не настоящим. А так можно ещё лемматизацию добавить через `pymorphy2`.

Comment: И ещё очень полезно брать те наблюдения, классы которых неправильно определились, и смотреть глазами - какой там был исходный текст и какие фичи для него нагенерились. Помогает понять, что не так, если сравнить их с правильными представителями класса. И там обычно понятно становится, каких фич не хватает, как ещё обработать. А так то ещё можно взять сразу какой-нибудь `fastText` и пусть он сам всё делает. Но лучше разобраться всё же с процессом "от печки" хотя бы раз самому.

Comment: @CrazyElf благодарю!